# Git accept all changes from Pull Request

Tags: git

I have a project that we just rewrote which completely changed the file structure of the application, and upgraded many parts of it. I no longer care what's in the master branch; I want the PR I created to replace everything in master with what's in the version-2 branch. I'm just not sure what command to use.

I created the PR in GitHub, but it can't automatically merge for me (obviously) but running `git merge dev` on the version-2 branch isn't working either, because I can't exactly tell if it's prioritizing the version-2 changes over anything in dev.

Hopefully this makes sense...which git command is the one I'm looking for? Again, when version-2 merges into master, I want version-2 to overwrite master in any potential merge conflict.

Comment: "but it can't automatically merge for me (obviously)". That's not obvious even with many changes. So something has changed already in the master.  Are you the repo owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "fake merge" by specifying a merge strategy `ours` dedicated for your case:

```
git checkout version-2
git merge -s our master -m "This is a brand new version 2"
git update-ref -m "Promote master to version-2" master refs/heads/version-2
git checkout master
git branch -D version-2 # if nobody needs version-2 anymore
```

This way is slightly longer than renaming branches, but it allows to keep the whole history of your project. All the users of the master branch will receive the major change without any additional effort.

Comment: We chose this route, but only the checkout of the version-2 branch, and then the git merge command. After that, I pushed and the PR in GitHub was able to be merged. We didn't try the rest of the commands here, but the first part did what we needed perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Probably you need to get rid of the outdated `master` branch at some point of your future development, but certainly it's not a strict rule, just a matter of  "house-keeping" activities

Comment: For what it's worth, this will not work if the branches don't share history (e.g. with `git checkout --orphan`).

Comment: Use `--allow-unrelated-histories` in `git merge...` if your development trees were completely independent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two branches do not share history, you don't need them to share history (e.g. for other remotes to `pull` from), and you'd like to promote `dev` in place of `master`, the easiest approach is merely to rename them:

```
git branch -m master old-version
git branch -m dev master
```

Note, this will not allow an existing repo elsewhere to `git pull` their `master` branch up to date. They could, however, `git fetch` and then `get checkout -b master --track origin/master`.